# Questions using an HTML5 video-tag 'src' URL in Google cloud storage

Tags: html, google-cloud-storage

I'm designing/developing a simple HTML5-based webpage.
But, rather than having the videos (e.g. MP4 and/or WEBM files)
based locally on the web-server, I want to store them all
in Google 'cloud-storage', by referencing them with a full
URL in the 'src' attribute of a  tag.

So, my first question is simply whether it's possible to derive 
such a reference URL, to a video file that I've uploaded into my 
Google acct's basic 15-GB of free storage?  (Or do I need
to first buy an 'official' starter unit of Google Cloud Storage?)

Secondly, could someone please point me to a tutorial or 'recipe'
for how to compute such a URL, so that I can build a simple initial
prototype to validate such a design approach.

TIA...

Dave

Comment: I've done many google-searches on issue of using one's free google-drive acct, and most everyone says that Google DID support that, but later dropped support for that.  (No one seems to say WHY that happened.)

Comment: The closest example I can find is http://sourcey.com/html5-video-streaming-from-google-drive/  but code is over 2-years old. (Back before Google dropped support, I suspect.)

Answer (score 2):

It's actually almost trivial (once I bit-the-bullet and registered
for a 60-day free trial of "Google Cloud Platform".)

It seems those older-style URLs (full of long strings of hex-chars)
are a thing of the past.  That actually makes sense, since the 
'bucket name' that you create to store your files in, must be
"globally-unique" and becomes part of the URL.

https://storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket-name/Steve_Jobs-2mins.mp4

So, it becomes as simple as just using their 'console' tool to create
a bucket, upload your file(s) into that bucket, declare each 'public/shared',
and then reference the resulting URL in the 'src' attribute of your
video or source HTML tag.

You can view my working example here:
    http://weasel.firmfriends.us/HTMLVideoFromCloud/

[ For details, you can 'view page source' on the HTML. ]

Cheers...

Dave